# Can not install modules - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Tags: python, pip, python-module

When trying to use pip or python from windows CMD, it throws me this warning:

```
Error processing line 1 of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\protobuf-3.7.0-py3.7-nspkg.pth:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
```

Other python scripts generally run fine. However, when trying to install SpaCy, this error is fatal, and the package can not be installed

I have tried reinstalling pip and python, and attempting to repair them from windows settings, with so success as of yet. Even just attempting to install pre-compiled binaries fails!

Even just typing `pip` into command prompt returns the same warning!

If anyone knows how to prevent this error, or find a workaround for installing packages, all answers are appreciated

Comment: Since even typing pip returns that error, have you tried reinstalling the pip?

Comment: yes, i have, however upon reinstalling pip all of my modules were still there, so maybe not all the files were deleted

Comment: I see. You mentioned 'The program generally runs fine', what do you mean by 'The program'?

Comment: sorry that was not clear, "the program" refers to any python scripts run through the command line, editing now

Comment: Sorry I can't help much. But, I think you might want to ask at https://superuser.com/ instead of this platform. You might have a better chance to get the solution also.

Comment: okay i will try superuser, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use lower char for installing package or it may be error of package try any other version